# setMnemonic() and call a method by pressing the key

Tags: java, swing, key, pressed, mnemonics

I have to run a method manually when pressing the key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

```
if("The key pressed==(Alt+H)"){
    callMethod();
}

public void callMethod(){
    //Some codes here
}
```

How I can actually do this in Java. Please give me a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's worth reading here about [Oracle Tutorial - Enabling Keyboard Operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic) where it is explained in details along with sample.

Read more about on [Oracle Tutorial - How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Some example directly from the above tutorial:

```
//Setting the mnemonic when constructing a menu item:
menuItem = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item",
                     KeyEvent.VK_H);

//Setting the mnemonic after creation time:
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);

//Setting the accelerator:
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_H, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
```

---

Read more here [Oracle Tutorial - How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Sample code: (`Alt-H` would click the Middle button)

```
JButton b2 = new JButton("Middle button", middleButtonIcon);
b2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
```

Answer (score 2):

If using menus then you can use `setMnemonic()`,  see [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for examples. Another option is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). For example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestKeys {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keys");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, InputEvent.ALT_MASK);

        Action testAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Alt-H pressed");
            }
        };

        frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke, "TestAction");
        frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("TestAction", testAction);       

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hit Alt-H");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best method is to use setMnemonic() because its the the simplest.

check this article for more http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JMenuBar-Set-Keyboard-Mnemonics-on-Menu-Items.html

```
private JMenu getColorMenu() {
  JMenu myMenu = new JMenu("Color");
  ButtonGroup myGroup = new ButtonGroup();

  JRadioButtonMenuItem myItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Red");
  myItem.setSelected(true);
  myItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
  myItem.addActionListener(this);
  myItem.addMenuKeyListener(this);
  myGroup.add(myItem);
  myMenu.add(myItem);

  myItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Green");
  myItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  myItem.addActionListener(this);
  myItem.addMenuKeyListener(this);
  myGroup.add(myItem);
  myMenu.add(myItem);

  myItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Blue");
  myItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  myItem.addActionListener(this);
  myItem.addMenuKeyListener(this);
  myGroup.add(myItem);
  myMenu.add(myItem);

  return myMenu;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, as it shows no way of using a key modifier like alt